# Chai check object contains only keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai

I'm trying to find out some chai replacement for only keyword that checks object contains ONLY listed keys.

There are my expectations:

`chai.expect({ x: 1, z: 1 }).to.contains.only.keys("x", "y")` fails

`chai.expect({ }).to.contains.only.keys("x", "y")` passes

`chai.expect({ x: 1 }).to.contains.only.keys("x", "y")` passes

Answer (score 7):

You should use [to.have.all.keys](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_keys)

```
expect({ x: 1 }).to.have.all.keys('x');
```

Comment: Updated samples it was incorrect. Can't apply this answer but there was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) to filter the object will get you what you want:

```
expect(_.omit({ x: 1, z: 1 }, ['x','y']), 'invalid properties').to.be.empty; /* fails */
expect(_.omit({ x: 1 }, ['x','y']), 'invalid properties').to.be.empty; /* passes */
expect(_.omit({ }, ['x','y']), 'invalid properties').to.be.empty; /* passes */
```